# How to understand code with vim?

Tags: vim, code-analysis

Vim is a nice editor and I use it for many tasks.

However, when it comes to start working on a new (possibly huge) codebase, I don't feel comfortable using it to go around the code with the objective of understanding how things work.

For example, if I want to see where a C++ function is used, I can `:vimgrep` for that function  in every `**/*.cpp` files and `:copen` the quickfix window to jump on every occurrence... of that string.

If I do the same with e.g. Eclipse (call hierarchy of a C++ method), that will not be just a string, but a C++ method defined in an object, so I will get a precise indication of the usages of that function (and not also a function with the same name defined in another class).

So the question is, how to make vim a powerful tool to analyze code?

Subquestions:

- Are there any vim plugins designed for this?
- Does it make sense to use vim to only analyze code? Probably external tools (e.g.: [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/)) can do the job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim is a text editor. What you want is almost completely orthogonal to editing text and completely outside of Vim's own abilities.

*However*, Vim is quite good at using external tools like [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) for navigating within a project. Supposing you have created a `tags` file and/or a `cscope.out` database, Vim has a bunch of commands you can use to "jump to definition", "jump to usage", etc.: `:ts[elect] foo`, `<C-]>` over a function name and so on… You can find all the info you need in `:h ctags` and `:h cscope`.

If you are curious, [GNU GLOBAL](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) is another alternative. Another pro of `cscope` is that it comes with its own TUI that you can use in your shell.

The only plugin offering a `cscope` (+ `ctags`) interface I know of is [CCTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2368) which seems to be limited to C.

There are a bunch of `ctags` oriented plugins like [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) or [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) you could try but note that, while `ctags` is limited to definitions, `cscope` can also do usage and callers.

You should keep in mind that these tools are code indexers: you shouldn't expect them to "understand" your code or be even remotely as precise as IDE tools. However I love Vim, I'd suggest you use a tool better suited to that task than a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

When I switched from Netbeans to Vim,  I felt the same as you. I missed Netbeans feature to see any function definition upon a right click. *Disclaimer: I use Ruby, Javascript mainly and sometimes PHP*

I tried ctags, but found it is not so accurate and not so clean. I also tried plugins Tagbar and Taglist using together with ctags.  Tagbar is a bit heavy in my opinion, takes lot of CPU and memory when handling tags. Taglist is better, but the best use case is to browse long files instead of tags.

Finally I gave up using ctags.

Later I found there are better solutions specific to language. For example, for Ruby there is a plugin to show ri doc of any function within installed gems(libs), with only one key.

But I still don't use that often as my habit already changed. I like things to be lean, to be in there right places, and to be fast.

Now I feel comfortable by:

1. Using tmux together with Vim. Check doc and verify code in console when needed.
2. Use snippet plugin(Neosnippet) to store frequently used codes, methods. The snippets management in Vim is far better and flexible than any IDE I've seen.
3. Use brain to store more, with less touching of mouse.

Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called fly.vim that is super awesome to browse source code. It makes use of a cscope database and provides simple navigation mechanism. Combine it with autotags plugin that generates and maintains cscope and ctags for a project in a central location, and you can switch between different code bases with ease.
I was using Source Insight to browse the Linux Kernel source code and when I switched over to this combination, I had nothing to complain. It may take some time and/or effort to get in speed with this setup, though. If you know how ctags and cscope work, then, probably you'll pick it up in less than an hour. But the advantages: cscope indexes code fast, vim uses cscope fast, fly.vim queries through cscope and displays it fast, and in a usable format. Plus, it maintains jump history.